# How to test IProfileService custom claims in a API using postman?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman

I have a Api service, which uses Custom claims, that has been added in the IProfileService IdentitySever4.

How can I populate those custom claims whilst sending the request from postman?

What I tried thus far -> Generated bearer token and added token as an Authorization header to invoke the API. API endpoint needs ClientNumber claim as mentioned below but userIdClaim always returning as null.

```
  ClaimsIdentity identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            Claim userIdClaim = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "ClientNumber").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: The profile service is responsible for putting claims into a token. Implement IProfileService and register it in DI. Your custom claim will involve in token , so you can firstly check whether that claim is in your token .

Comment: I have the same problem. I created a profile service that implements IProfileService and added it to the IdentityServer Registration in startup. But it doesn't get called up when I request a token from Postman. I don't have an application client yet but I need to test my API and I can't because the token generated doesn't add the claims I need for authorization on my API.

Comment: It may only fire for authorization_code grant type. What grant type is your postman client?